# keras download error - TypeError: sting argument expected, got "Nonetype"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, keras, theano

I have been attempting for weeks to get keras working, and still have not had success.  I am running Python 3.5 through Anaconda 4.3.0 and spyder and I have a 64-bit processor.

My latest attempt involve uninstalling everything, reinstalling Anaconda 4.3.0 with python 3.5.  I then did the following:

```
conda create --name neuralnets python=3.5
activate neuralnets
conda install theano
conda install mingw libpython
pip install tensoflow
```

All of this worked fine.  I then did "pip install keras," and got the following:

```
Collecting keras
  Downloading Keras-2.0.5.tar.gz (216kB)
    100% |################################| 225kB 883kB/s
Collecting theano (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\dwpri\anaconda1\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\dwpri\anaconda1\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\dwpri\anaconda1\lib\site-packages (from theano->keras)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in c:\users\dwpri\anaconda1\lib\site-packages (from theano->keras)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dwpri\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\dwpri\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\dwpri\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\dwpri\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\dwpri\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 666, in _prepare_file
    check_dist_requires_python(dist)
  File "C:\Users\dwpri\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\packaging.py", line 48, in check_dist_requires_python
    feed_parser.feed(metadata)
  File "C:\Users\dwpri\Anaconda1\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 178, in feed
    self._input.push(data)
  File "C:\Users\dwpri\Anaconda1\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 104, in push
    self._partial.write(data)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'NoneType'
```

Please advise as to what I can do.  I'm extremely frustrated and could really use the assistance.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any solution? I have the same installing Spacy in the same way as you've installed tensorflow

Comment: What worked for me was playing around with using pip or conda to install keras and tensorflow.  I'm not sure exactly which was which, I think when I used conda to install tensorflow it worked.  Hopefully that helps.